# iPhone SDK NSString To NSDate

Tags: iphone, date, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I got a string from parsing a XML file which looks like this: Fri, 09 Apr 2010 00:00:45 +0200
and the corresponding pattern should be this "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ", but I get (null).

This is my code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Fri, 09 Apr 2010 00:00:45 +0200";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date:%@",date); // result date:(null)
```

Edit:

This works for me now, I had to switch to en-US locale:

```
NSLocale* usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: don't forget to release your dateFormater & usLocale !

Comment: The reason for this is that your device 12/24 setting is contrary to the locale.  This causes Apple to "help" you by changing the "HH:mm:ss" to "hh:mm:ssa".  Using the en-US locale disables this "feature".  (Though en_US_POSIX is better.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code worked for me when I changed this line:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
```

to this line:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
```

Comment: Strangely it's still giving me null result. iPhone SDK 3.1.2

Comment: It works when the string is "Fr." instead of "Fri", which probably happens because it looks for a german timeformat.