# Convert NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

I make a request to the flickr api and it returns me the date in the following format

```
"2013-02-01T06:25:47Z"
```

How do i convert this into NSDate format??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618807/iphone-sdk-nsstring-to-nsdate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251777/how-do-i-convert-from-nsstring-to-nsdate

Comment: @vivian: I'll not downvote u(cuz u already get lots of!), but wanna tell u that, as u r gold badge holder(!).. so while posting any question here, just do some research first and then post question if needed...! Thanks

Comment: Dude - I am not here for votes - If I get a solution -My job is accomplished - So thanks for your concern. There are a lot of free people who will answer questions just for points - Why not use this resource... I love stackoverflow :)

Comment: for those who are looking how to transform the next time format: __2014-05-12T19:52:56.244Z__ here's the appropriate date formatter format: __[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];__

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a simple one, converting NSString to NSDate we use NSDateformatter using dateFromString method. We need to provide the Dateformatter style with existing style for NSString

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-01T06:25:47Z"];
NSTimeZone *pdt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:pdt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"K:mm a, z"];
NSString * updated String = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Not an answer.  Explain the code above.

Comment: Its simple one, converting NSString to NSDate we use NSDateformatter using dateFromString method. We need to provide the Dateformatter style with existing style for NSString.

Comment: @Madhu, yes, now put that in your answer.  Code blocks are worthless learning tools without an explanation/a little documentation.

Comment: @yucelbayram Your welcome :-) Please up-vote for my answer if you think it worths.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below function:

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)pstrDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *dtPostDate = [df1 dateFromString:pstrDate];
    return dtPostDate;
}
```

Hope, it will be helpful to you.

This function will accept your string date and return the NSDate value.

Cheers!